# Run through elements of an array HTML

Tags: html, arrays

I am new to HTML and I have to modify a certain snippet of code so that it meets my needs. Here is the snippet, in pseudocode:

```
<app-myapp *ngIf="true"
                    [exclude] = "[this.myUser.id]"
                    ">
</app-myapp>
```

Now what I need to do is the following: I also have an array of numbers inside the attribute `myUser` of my class called `excludedUsers`, and I want to include all the elements of this array in the `[exclude]` array that I am passing to my app. Obviously this does not work: `[exclude] = "[this.myUser.id, this.myUser.excludedUsers]"`, because `this.myUser.excludedUsers` is an array. I do not know if a `ngFor` could work here. Could someone help me?

Comment: None of that is HTML and you are going to have to include information as to what that is you are working with and tagging it.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple. It's called spread syntax and it expands all elements of an array into an array declaration.

```
[this.myUser.id, ...this.myUser.excludedUsers]
```